# How to obtain the date information from a web page, using C#?

Tags: html, datetime, html-parsing, web-crawler

I am currently writing a small crawler program trying to fetch web pages and index them.

I would like to know when the web page was produced or about.

For example, a news page for a date normally was created on that day around.

How can I accurately obtain the date?

One naive idea is to obtain the date from the HTML. Normally a news or blog page will somewhere write the date. But since HTML does not have a specific tag for it, how can I get it?

try out different possible date format?

Anyone can give me some suggestions? or is there any library I can use?

Thanks

Comment: Well the thing with scraping .. is that its a nightmare because of things that you ecperience. You can only build an engine to search for keywords like "date" and try to parse numbers near that text if reading blogs etc. but sometimes looking at the pages cache pragma, the field last modified(for cahcing purposes) could be a good starting point.  Good luck

Comment: @ppumkin what do you mean by "pages cache pragma"?